# Unable to interface mpu6050 with RPI PICO with micropython

Tags: i2c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, mpu6050

Unable to interface mpu6050 with RPI PICO with micropython.

```
import machine
import utime

MPU6050_ADDR = 0x68  # MPU6050 I2C address

def read_i2c_word(i2c, address):
    # Read a 16-bit word from the specified I2C address
    return (i2c.readfrom_mem(address, 0x3B, 2)[0] << 8) | i2c.readfrom_mem(address, 0x3C, 2)[1]

def read_accel_gyro(i2c):
    # Read accelerometer and gyroscope data
    accel_x = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR)
    accel_y = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR + 2)
    accel_z = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR + 4)

    gyro_x = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR + 8)
    gyro_y = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR + 10)
    gyro_z = read_i2c_word(i2c, MPU6050_ADDR + 12)

    return (accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z)

def main():
    i2c = machine.I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(0), scl=machine.Pin(1), freq=400000)  # I2C bus on Pico

    while True:
        accel_data = read_accel_gyro(i2c)
        print("Accelerometer (X, Y, Z):", accel_data[:3])
        print("Gyroscope (X, Y, Z):", accel_data[3:])
        print("")

        utime.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Throwed this error on Thony ide:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 34, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 26, in main
File "<stdin>", line 13, in read_accel_gyro
File "<stdin>", line 8, in read_i2c_word OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

tried with different Pico boards and different mpu6050 modules. Same issue